# Many new MySQL columns with one form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, alter

I want to put a form on my website to let users add events to their private calendar. For that, I would like to create a new column in MySQL each time the user add an event (always with the same form, one column for each event title, for example...)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

However, would it not be better to have a table called 'events' that holds all of them, with a column called 'userid' which contains the ID of the user the event belongs to.

Then you would know that every event exists in that table, and to get a users events you simply query that one table for rows that contain the users ID in the userid column.

Comment: For alter_table, I knew it... but do you know a way to always add a column at the end of the table with the same form?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's a very very very bad idea.

Add a table userevents, add a record to that. To get the output you want, have look for how to do pivot queries in mysql.

Comment: Is there a way, while the user add an event to the userevents table, to automaticlly add a column that say for exemple (event 1, event 3...) for each new row created?

Comment: Just refresh the pivot query.? It's not going to be clever but adding a column to the users table has the same issue. Personally I'd think of another way to display what you want. This is going to be a tin of worms no matter which end of the can you open.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of app. You can use magic **websql** (client side database)!

> Web SQL Database is a web page API for storing data in databases that can queried using a variant of SQL.

**More:** http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/